# Implementation of Integrator in PID control

Tags: pid-controller

I have a doubt in implementing PID control. I referred many documents and video tutorials regarding this. But I am quite confused regarding the implementation of integrator in PID control. I could see that there are two ways used for implementing the integrator.

1. Method 1
   IntegralError = IntegralError + error;
2. Method 2
   pid->integrator = pid->integrator + 0.5f * pid->Ki * pid->T * (error + pid->prevError);

   I found this code above from this [example](https://github.com/pms67/PID/blob/master/PID.c)

The first method is straight forward. I can understand it. But the second method is not clear to me. What is the role of pid->prevError? How integration is achieved here? Which of the above methods are more efficient?

Please help me on this

Thanks,
Varun

I tried the first method. It works. But I cannot understand the second method.

Comment: I'm afraid you're on the wrong stack exchange site. This one is only about programming. See a complete list of se sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#). You probably want [robotics.se] or [electronics.se]. Or maybe just [engineering.se], which has a section on mechanical engineering.

Comment: @JHBonarius, Thanks for your reply. I posted this question on electronics stack exchange and I got the answer.
The second method I mentioned uses trapezoidal rule for integrating